# I get conditional exception even though the request meets condition in AppSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, vtl

### Overview

I am quite new to AppSync.

### Issue

I could not limit PutItem command even though I set a condition in resolver.

Query

```
mutation MyMutation {
  createTodo(input: {description: "test", name: "test2"}) {
    id
    description
    name
  }
}
```

Result

```
{
  "data": {
    "createTodo": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "createTodo"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": null,
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "The conditional request failed (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: XXX"
    }
  ]
}
```

Resolver

```
{
  "operation": "PutItem",
  "key": {
    "id": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($util.autoId())
  },
  "attributeValues" : {
        "name"    : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.input.name),
        "description"    : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.input.description)
  },
  "condition": {
    "expression": "description = :sizeValue",
    "expressionValues": {
      ":sizeValue": {
        "S":"test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In above example, I set "test" in description. So, I think there should be no conditional exception. However, I get error message saying "The conditional request failed".

I checked the CloudWatch log.

```
"transformedTemplate": "{\n  \"operation\": \"PutItem\",\n  \"key\": {\n    \"id\": {\"S\":\"xxx\"}\n  },\n  \"attributeValues\" : {\n        \"name\"    : {\"S\":\"test2\"},\n        \"description\"    : {\"S\":\"test\"}\n  },\n  \"condition\": {\n    \"expression\": \"description = :sizeValue\",\n\t\"expressionValues\": {\n      \":sizeValue\": {\n        \"S\":\"test\"\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}"
}
```

↓ (After formatting)

```
{
  "operation": "PutItem",
  "key": {
    "id": {"S":"xxx"}
  },
  "attributeValues" : {
        "name"    : {"S":"test2"},
        "description"    : {"S":"test"}
  },
  "condition": {
    "expression": "description = :sizeValue",
    "expressionValues": {
      ":sizeValue": {
        "S":"test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Based on the above log, I think the request should satisfy the condition.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to solve the issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written a PutItem request which states:

Save item `"id": {"S":"xxx"}` only if the item is already stored in DynamoDB and has a value for `description` which equals `test`.

I believe you think the condition is based on what you set for attributes in the request, but conditions are for evaluating items state already stored in DynamoDB.

So in summary, you get a `ConditionCheckFailedException` because you don't have an item in your DynamoDB table with an `id=test2` and `description=test`. This is what you require for your condition to evaluate to true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I could resolve it with your answer. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent. Feel free to accept and/or upvote the answer.